# how to bypass the second round of activation function outputs in sparse autoencoders?

Tags: deep-learning, sparse-matrix, autoencoder

[In this article from Andrew Ng](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder.pdf), he mentioned for large datasets, "you would end up computing a forward pass twice on each example in your training set". This is because we need to find the average of activation functions before calculating the loss function. I am wondering after 9 years if there is any way to bypass the second pass? Do TensorFlow and PyTorch the second pass?

My main question is that 'is this second pass still a common thing in nowadays application?'

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure this question has a single answer. Generally, questions here are more practical based. I'd recommend a [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).